# I want to run a job every 4 hours starting from 9 AM Wednesday till 8:59 AM Thursday in Autosys

Tags: autosys

I have given the below conditions to run every 4 hours during those days, but the problem is the job is running at 01:00, 05:00 and 08:58 on Wednesdays. I expect the job to run from 09:00 AM Wednesday till 08:59 AM Thursday.

insert_job: file_watcher.0000.000   job_type: BOX

date_conditions: 1

days_of_week: we,th

start_times: "09:00,13:00,17:00,21:00,01:00,05:00,08:59"

run_window: "09:00 - 08:59"

description: "File watcher job"

Could someone guide me how to modify the conditions to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by 1 job definition.
Suggest you, create 2 jobs one for Wed and Thurs with their respective timings.